# overwrite the phpinfo() function?

Tags: php

I was curious and was wondering if there was a way for me to make my own phpinfo() function?

```
function phpinfo() {
   // show custom list of php.ini settings here
}
```

i tried this but i get a parse error because i named my function the same as the PHP built-in function.

I know you can change the way phpinfo() outputs its data (colors etc) but I haven't found a way where I can filter the content of the page.

I am letting people make sub domain when they register and with that i am letting them host their own files, but i wan't to limit the phpinfo output so that they can only see what i let them see.

I have full control over my PHP installation as I am running my site off a dedicated server if that helps any.

Comment: What in `phpinfo` don't you want them to see?

Comment: You are giving them the ability to execute code on your server.  Trying to limit the data in phpinfo is a waste of time.

Comment: true, but i want to customize it to show the most important settings in one group to make it easier and faster to look thru.

Comment: @s2xi: That's what the find/search feature is for?

Comment: yes, but i want to customize every aspect of my CMS i am making and pass on that unique look and feel to my registered users. I am trying to simplify the process for my users when they want to make their own hosted applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename the old `phpinfo` using [`runkit_function_rename`](http://www.php.net/runkit_function_rename). After you've renamed it, you can define a new function named `phpinfo`. If you need to call the old function, just call it by its new name. Alternatively, if you don't need to call the old function, you can remove it using [`runkit_function_remove`](http://www.php.net/runkit_function_remove).

The problem with these solutions is if they knew the name you renamed it to, they could call that to get the original output. The best solution is probably to modify the PHP source to filter what `phpinfo` outputs.

**Edit:** Here's an example of how you might use `runkit_function_rename`. I don't have `runkit` installed so I can't test to see if it works or not, but it might:

```
runkit_function_rename('phpinfo', 'old_phpinfo');

function phpinfo() {
    ob_start();
    old_phpinfo();
    $data=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $data=str_replace("php", "(the language you're using)", $data);
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: thats brilliant! i want to make my own wrapper for the default phpinfo() and this just might do the trick. Hmmm, where do I use the `runkit_function_name` can you give me a quick dirty usage example please.

Comment: ya, im sorry i didn't see that you had masked the links! I just finished reading the php docs on this. Thank you sooo much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the php.ini directive `disable_functions` to disable the standard phpinfo function which would allow you to define your own. See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php.

I don't think this is a great route to go down though. You need to be able to trust people you are allowing to upload code to your server. I don't think there's much in the phpinfo() output that couldn't be got trivially by other means.

Comment: im not trying to censor my users, i am just trying to recreate the output with my unique style to match my custom CMS as well as make the  output easier to navigate through. Put all the important commonly used extension settings near the top and so on.